# If $\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt\rightarrow \infty$ as $|x|\rightarrow \infty\;,$ Then every line $y=mx$ Intersect $ y^2+\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt=2$

Tags: calculus

> If $f$ is a continuous function with $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt\rightarrow \infty$ as $|x|\rightarrow \infty\;,$ Then show that every line
>
> $y=mx$ Intersect the curve $\displaystyle y^2+\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt=2$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Put $y=mx$ in $$\displaystyle y^2+\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt=2\;,$$ We get $$\displaystyle m^2x^2+y^2+\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt=2.$$

We can write it as $$\displaystyle 2\int_{0}^{x}2m^2tdt+\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt=2$$

So $$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{x}\left[2m^2t+f(t)\right]dt-2 =0$$

Now Let $$g(x) = \displaystyle \int_{0}^{x}\left[2m^2t+f(t)\right]dt-2.\;,$$ When $x\rightarrow \infty\;,$ Then $g(x)\rightarrow \infty.$

(Where $g(x)$ is an Continuous function.)

Now I did not Understand How can i solve that, Help me

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't $g$ be a function of $x$? Then as $x \to \infty$, $g(x) \to \infty$, implying there exists some $M$ such that $g$ is positive for $x > M$. Since $g(0) = -2$, by the intermediate value theorem there is some $x$ such that $g(x) = 0$.

Comment: @Nitin You are absolutely correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show that every line $y=mx$ intersects the curve $y^2+\int _{ 0 }^{ x }{ f(t)dt=2!}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1495450/show-that-every-line-y-mx-intersects-the-curve-y2-int-0-x-ftdt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $g: x \mapsto \int_{0}^{x} 2m^{2}t + f(t) dt - 2$ on $\mathbb{R}$ is continuous, and since $g(x) > 0$ for large $x$ and $< 0$ for $x = 0$, by Bolzano's theorem we have $g(c) = 0$ for some $c$ between $0$ and the point at which $g > 0$.

Comment: We don't know the behavior of $g$ for $x\to -\infty$.  But we do know that $g(0)=-2<0$ and $g\to \infty$ as $x\to \infty$.  And that should do it!

Comment: @Dr.MV: Thank you. Just noticed that it is not the hypothesis in the OP :)

Comment: You're welcome!!  My pleasure.  +1 for the edited answer ... well done!