# Show that every line $y=mx$ intersects the curve $y^2+\int _{ 0 }^{ x }{ f(t)dt=2!}$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

> If $f$ is a continuous function with $\displaystyle \int _{ 0 }^{ x}{
>  f(t)dt\rightarrow\infty }  $ as $|x|\rightarrow\infty$,then show that
>    every line
>
> $y=mx$ intersects the curve $\displaystyle y^2+\int _{ 0 }^{ x }{
>  f(t)dt=2!}  $

I can't understand how to proceed with this problem.Any suggestion?

Comment: Is m a constant or a variable?

Comment: @Aniket Its a constant.

Comment: Your integrand contains a function of t and limits t and 0. Where does x come from? BTW please change the limit t to something else. Looks a bit bad that the variable and limit are same.

Comment: As $\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt\to\infty$as $x\to\infty$,this means $\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt\to\infty$ cuts the curve two times.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out @Aniket.

Comment: Is this some jee question?

Comment: @VinodKumarPunia yes..but i don't know the year..

Answer (score 4):

Set : $\displaystyle g(x)= (mx)^2+\int_0^x f(t)\ \mathrm{d}t$, $g$ is continuous since it is the sum of two continuous

(and also differentiable) functions.

We have :  $g(0)=0$, and : $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to \infty} g(x)= +\infty$, for any $m\in \mathbb{R}$ .

So the equation : $g(x)=\alpha$ has a solution for any $\alpha \geq 0$.

Here we have $\alpha =2$

Answer (score 1):

Consider a function 
$$F(x)=y^2+\int _{ 0 }^{ x}f(t)dt-2$$.

$F(x)$ is continuous as $f(x)$ is continuous.

Putting $y=mx$ in the equation of F(x).

$$F(x)={m^2x^2}+\int _{ 0 }^{ x}f(t)dt-2$$

Clearly $F(0)=-2$

$F(x)\rightarrow\infty$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$ so somewhere F(x) must exceed 0 and hence somewhere F(x) is indeed 0.

So y=mx surely intersects the line!

P.S:My solution is quite similar to @juantheron though :-)!